# <Python/KNN>IndexError: index 59 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 59

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, knn

There is a problem even though the size of the Excel is correct.
It keeps happening on line 101, I don't know what the problem is. I marked the part where the error appears below. I need your help.

```
class m_KNN:
    gaits = [] # gait's list


    def CalculateDistance(self, gait1, gait2):
        gx = np.square(gait1.GyroscopeX - gait2.GyroscopeX)
        gy = np.square(gait1.GyroscopeY - gait2.GyroscopeY)
        gz = np.square(gait1.GyroscopeZ - gait2.GyroscopeZ)
        ax = np.square(gait1.AccelerometerX - gait2.AccelerometerX)
        ay = np.square(gait1.AccelerometerY - gait2.AccelerometerY)
        az = np.square(gait1.AccelerometerZ - gait2.AccelerometerZ)
        mx = np.square(gait1.MagnetometerX - gait2.MagnetometerX)
        my = np.square(gait1.MagnetometerY - gait2.MagnetometerY)
        mz = np.square(gait1.MagnetometerZ - gait2.MagnetometerZ)
        return np.sqrt(gx+gy+gz+ax+ay+az+mx+my+mz)

    def GetNearestList(self, gait, k): # Get the nearest data list number of K from test data
        distanceDataList = []
        nearestDataList = []

        for i in range(len(self.gaits)): # for making test data <-> training data's distance list
            distanceDataList.append(self.CalculateDistance(self.gaits[i], gait))

        for i in range(k): # for making the NearestDataList number of K
            nearestDataList.append(distanceDataList.index(min(distanceDataList)))
            distanceDataList.remove(min(distanceDataList))

        return nearestDataList


    def WeightedMajorityVote(self, answer): 

        targetClassList = []

        bias = -0.5 


        weight0 = 0.2
        weight1 = 0.3
        weight2 = 0.5

        length = len(answer)
        for i in range(length):
            targetClassList.append(self.gaits[answer[i]].targetClass)

        normalCount = targetClassList[:length//3].count(0) * weight2 + targetClassList[length//3:2*length//3].count(0) * weight1 + targetClassList[2*length//3:].count(0) * weight0 + bias
        abnormalCount = targetClassList[:length//3].count(1) * weight2 + targetClassList[length//3:2*length//3].count(1) * weight1 + targetClassList[2*length//3:].count(1) * weight0 + bias

        maxIdx = 0


        if(abnormalCount > normalCount) :
            maxIdx = 1

        if(maxIdx == 1):
            return 'abnormal'
        else:
            return 'normal'



class GaitData: # gaitdata 1 row
    def __init__(self, data, targetClass):
        self.GyroscopeX = data[0]
        self.GyroscopeY = data[1]
        self.GyroscopeZ = data[2]
        self.AccelerometerX = data[3]
        self.AccelerometerY = data[4]
        self.AccelerometerZ = data[5]
        self.MagnetometerX = data[6]
        self.MagnetometerY = data[7]
        self.MagnetometerZ = data[8]
        self.targetClass = targetClass

m_knn = m_KNN()


gait = pd.read_csv('normal_LX.csv',  usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
target = pd.read_csv('normal_LX.csv', usecols=[9])

gait_data = {'data': np.array(gait, dtype=object), 'target': np.array(target)}

k = 3

for iter in range(len(gait_data['target'])):

    if (iter % 15 == 0 and iter != 0):
        None
    else:
        m_knn.gaits.append(
            GaitData(gait_data['data'][iter], gait_data['target'][iter]))

print("\nWeighted Majority Vote\n\n")
```

This is the part of the code where the error occurs:

```
for t in range(10): 


    iter = 15 * (t + 1) - 1
    print("Test Data Index is", t, end='/')

    print("Computed Class is", m_knn.WeightedMajorityVote(m_knn.GetNearestList(GaitData(gait_data['data'][iter], gait_data['target'][iter]),k)), end = ' / ')

    if (np.any(gait_data['target'] == 0)):
        print("True Class is normal", "\n")
    else:
        print("True Class is abnormal", "\n")
```

#### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\simja\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 101, in <module>
    print("Computed Class is", m_knn.WeightedMajorityVote(m_knn.GetNearestList(GaitData(gait_data['data'][iter], gait_data['target'][iter]),k)), end = ' / ')
IndexError: index 59 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 59
```

Comment: Check how many rows your dataframe `gait` has, with `len(gait)` or `gate.shape`.

Comment: I suspect that `len(gait_data['data']) == iter == 59`. Python is 0-indexed, so index `59` is off-by-one from the end of the array. Also: given `t = 9`, `iter = 15 * 10 - 1 = 149`. Are you sure your array has that many entries?